# Facebook Custom Application Deployment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a small Facebook application that let users post pictures on my web site to their Facebook timeline.

I assume that any apps implementing publish actions like this (excluding feed/share dialogs) require review by Facebook.

When you are planning to deploy an app on multiple web sites under different domains, will you have to go through the review multiple times for each domain?

Comment: Yes, you will, because you need a separate app id for each domain.

Comment: @CBroe If your app will not have any UI, what sort of screenshots are required for the review? Do you know anything related to this by any chance?

Comment: They will want to see at least how users will be triggering a share from within your application, and what the resulting posts will look like on timeline.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Really helpful.